# I'm getting wrong char while tracing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to check char of a textfield but it traces wrong char. Here's my code

```
function onGrFormulaChange(event:Event):void {      
    if (groupingFormula_txt.text.length != 1) {
        if (groupingFormula_txt.text != "") {
            if (String(groupingFormula_txt.text.charAt(groupingFormula_txt.length - 1) == "+")) {
                trace(groupingFormula_txt.text.charAt(groupingFormula_txt.length - 1)); // outputs /
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code traces "/". Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong? I'm using Adobe flash Professional cc 2014.

Comment: Do a trace `groupingFormula_txt.length` and `groupingFormula_txt.text.length`, these two are pretty different values, one even might be undefined.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i tried it, a few traces output new line.

Comment: Change to `if (String(groupingFormula_txt.text.charAt(groupingFormula_txt.text.length - 1) == "+"))`

Comment: thank you for the answer. your code does the same thing, it outputs forward slash.

Comment: @DodgerThud You needed to add that he has to change the trace statement as well. :)

Comment: d'oh. thanks for noticing. In general I think it would be easier to store the text value in a temporary string.

Comment: i already did it. i changed "if" and trace statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, as Vesper correctly pointed out, the length property of a string and the length Object of any other type of Object are quite different.

Try this:

```
function onGrFormulaChange(event:Event):void {      
    var text:String = groupingFormula_txt.text;
    if (text.length != 1) {
        if (text != "") {
            var lastChar:String = text.charAt(text.length-1);
            if(lastChar=="+"){
                trace(lastChar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work correctly, please trace out what groupinFormula_txt.text holds and tell us what it is, i.e.

```
function onGrFormumlaChange(e:Event):void{
    var text:String = groupingFormula_txt.text;
    trace(text);
    ...
```